# Using lbsvm in Matlab with Excel data

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, libsvm

My data are in Excel, so to convert them in `Libsvm` format, I convert the Excel sheet to CSV format and follow the procedure on Libsvm web site:- assuming the CSV file is SPECTF.train : -

> matlab> SPECTF = csvread('SPECTF.train'); % read a csv file
>
> matlab> labels = SPECTF(:, 1); % labels from the 1st column
>
> matlab> features = SPECTF(:, 2:end);
>
> matlab> features_sparse = sparse(features); % features must be in a
>   sparse matrix
>
> matlab> libsvmwrite('SPECTFlibsvm.train', labels, features_sparse);

Then I read it using `libsvmread` (name)

Is there a shorter way to format excel data in Libsvm format directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need to convert to csv. You can use xlsread to read the data directly from the excel file and use libsvmwrite to get that in the form compatible with libsvm.